# How to create google search box style textbox with clickable image on the right in Textbox?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a textbox inside which there will a picture and I can click on the picture to perform any action. The picture must has to positioned relative to the textbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make a div with 1px border and put there an input with no border and next to the input - a submit button with an image on the background :)

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergiu/hvBQk/

Comment: just added input:focus{outline:none;} in the css. http://jsfiddle.net/d3ep4k/nm46P/